# window.open(referrerURL) with window.open(anotherURL) do not allow any action on referrerURL

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have list of URL`s on a page(Parent Page). When i click on a URL, it opens a page in the same window that calls another URL(Child Page) that opens in another window.

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Now the page that called the Child Page is redirected back to the Parent Page using

```
window.open(referrer, "_self");
```

but the parent page(referrer) do not allow any action or none of the links are clickable until the Child Page completes loading.

**Complete Code**

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
var windowobj = window.open(url, "_blank");
windowobj.focus();
window.open(referrer, "_self");
```

Comment: What’s the purpose of this, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Well i cannot answer that as it has been a requirement for some of the reasons but now i want to sort out this issue.